# Angular 13 - how to apply click outside directive on a component with instances?

Tags: angular

I'm encountering an issue with a component that includes a textarea. The purpose of this component is to enable text editing when it's clicked. When the text is clicked, an edit mode is activated, and the textarea displays the text for editing.

The problem I'm facing is that if I click only on the text itself, rather than inside the textarea, the edit mode doesn't get canceled when I click outside of it. However, if I click inside the textarea, the behavior is correct, and the edit mode is canceled as expected.

I've tried unsuccessfuly to apply "click ouside" event handler - but i'm not sure that's the direction.

[enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hsz6gc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Ftext-edit%2Ftext-edit.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts&file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Ftext-edit%2Ftext-edit.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize "click out" event, but you have to do it in a different way - not using `HostBinding`. Tap into [`ngAfterViewInit`](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) hook and add the following code:

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  fromEvent(document, 'click')
    .pipe(filter((event) => (event.target as HTMLElement).tagName !== 'SPAN'))
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.save();
    });
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gngmrf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Ftext-edit%2Ftext-edit.component.ts)

---

### Update: VERY IMPORTANT!

You have to unsubscribe from that `subscribe` manually, since it's an ongoing subscription. It's simply a [RxJS stuff](https://www.twilio.com/blog/prevent-memory-leaks-angular-observable-ngondestroy). So your modified code should look like:

```js
private clickSub?: Subscription;
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.clickSub = fromEvent(document, 'click')
    .pipe(filter((event) => (event.target as HTMLElement).tagName !== 'SPAN'))
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.save();
    });
}
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.clickSub?.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Brillient - thanks!

Comment: I forgot to do one IMPORTANT thing! You have to unsubscribe form that subscription when the component is destroyed. Otherwise it'll cause memory leaks. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I'm now facing another issue - hope you might help.The default mode for empty fields is Edit, so once i clicked on non empty value - all the text fields are disappears, i've updated the link

Comment: Change `(event.target as HTMLElement).tagName !== 'SPAN')` to `!['SPAN', 'TEXTAREA'].includes((event.target as HTMLElement).tagName)`.